# Tree selection clears when data model refresh

Tags: qt, qabstractitemmodel, qsortfilterproxymodel

I have a treeview in which I have applied sorting/filtering using `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

When I perform some action on tree item(ex. RMB action), I refresh my data `model(QAbstractItemModel)`.

I am using `beginresetmodel()` before refreshing my data model. After data model's refreshed, selection on selected item disappears. I have saved the selections before refreshing data model, and applied them back after the model is refreshed, but the items do not get selected.

I tried removing `beginResetModel()` before refreshing data model, and selection works fine in that case.

[QSortFilterProxyModel documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#filtering) says:

> However, `beginResetModel()` / `endResetModel()` returns the proxy model to its original state, losing selection information, and will cause the proxy model to be repopulated."

How can I retain selection while keeping `beginResetModel()` / `endResetModel()` when refreshing data model?

Comment: Details can be found in this thread on Qt Forum: [tree selection clears when data model refresh](https://forum.qt.io/topic/145241/tree-selection-clears-when-data-model-refresh/9?_=1684739336924)

Answer (score -1):

I am able to fix this by refreshing the seleced rows instead of reloading complete data model.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).